# Parse a list of subroutines

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lexical-analysis, ocamllex, ocamlyacc

I have written `parser_sub.mly` and `lexer_sub.mll` which can parse a `subroutine`. A `subroutine` is a block of statement englobed by `Sub` and `End Sub`.

Actually, the raw file I would like to deal with contains a list of subroutines and some useless texts. Here is an example:

```
' a example file
Sub f1()
  ...
End Sub
haha
' hehe
Sub f2()
  ...
End Sub
```

So I need to write `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll` which can parse this file by ignoring all the comments (e.g. `haha`, `' hehe`, etc.) and calling `parser_sub.main`, and returns a list of subroutines.

1. Could anyone tell me how to let the parser ignore all the useless sentences (sentences outside a `Sub` and `End Sub`)?

   Here is a part of `parser.mly` I tried to write:

   ```
   %{
     open Syntax
   %}
   %start main
   %type <Syntax.ev> main
   %%
   main:
     subroutine_declaration*  { $1 };

   subroutine_declaration:
     SUB name = subroutine_name LPAREN RPAREN EOS
     body = procedure_body?
     END SUB 
     { { subroutine_name = name;
         procedure_body_EOS_opt = body; } }
   ```
2. The rules and parsing for `procedure_body` are complex and are actually defined in `parser_sub.mly` and `lexer_sub.mll`, so how could I let `parser.mly` and `lexer.mll` do not repeat defining it, and just call `parser_sub.main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the stuff you want so skip can have any form (not necessarily valid tokens of your language), you pretty much have to solve this by hacking your lexer, as Kakadu suggests. This may be the easiest thing in any case.

If the filler (stuff to skip) consists of valid tokens, and you want to skip using a grammar rule, it seems to me the main problem is to define a nonterminal that matches any token other than END. This will be unpleasant to keep up to date, but seems possible.

Finally you have the problem that your end marker is two symbols, END SUB. You have to handle the case where you see END not followed by SUB. This is even trickier because SUB is your beginning marker also. Again, one way to simplify this would be to hack your lexer so that it treats END SUB as a single token. (Usually this is trickier than you'd expect, say if you want to allow comments between END and SUB.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can set some flag when we are inside subroutine:

```
sub_starts:
  SUB { inside:=true };
sub_ends:
  ENDSUB { inside:=false };    
subroutine_declaration:
  sub_starts name body sub_ends { ... }
```

And when this flag is not set you just skip any input?